# take the name of the month in date format

Tags: excel, vba

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aNsi.jpg

I learned VBA from scratch and started simple.

I just want to display the month name from the date format in Column B2: B690, and put it in Column A2: A690 .. but my code has an error.

can you help me find the right solution in coding?

```
Dim rng1, rng2 As Range

Set rng1 = Range("A2:A690") 
Set rng2 = Range("B2:B690")

rng1.Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(rng2, "mmmm")
```

Comment: Please, try `rng1.NumberFormat = "MMMM"`... And never post code in a picture. Please, edit your question and paste the code as it is, explaining on which line, which error appears.

Comment: Kostas K.

Thank you for responding to the posts I made, this is my first time joining this group, sorry if something goes wrong when I start posting for the first time.

but the advice you give I will try to apply.

Comment: Didn't my code do what you you need? Please, refresh the page (this one) before using the code. The version you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Dim rng1, rng2 As Range

 Set rng2 = Range("B2:B690")
 rng2.Copy Range("A2")
 
 Set rng1 = Range("A2:A690")
 rng1.NumberFormat = "MMMM"
```

Or avoiding the use of clipboard:

```
Sub testTextMonthName()
  Dim rng1, rng2 As Range
  
  Set rng1 = Range("A2:A690")
  Set rng2 = Range("B2:B690")
  
  With rng1
     .Value2 = rng2.Value2
     .NumberFormat = "MMMM"
     '.value = .Text 'if you need it as text, uncomment this line, please
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the advice you gave, but it didn't work as expected. Range A2: A690 cannot retrieve month data which is in Range B2: B690.

Comment: @RIDWAN: This should not happen... So, is the range "B2:B690" copied in the range "A2:A690"? If not, are you sure you copied the code as it is? Please, refresh the page (this one)... If yes, are there the Date, but not correctly formated?

Comment: Omg, yeah .. I missed the range "B2: B690" which was copied to the "A2: A690" range ..

and after I did that, it finally worked, the code you provided was running as I expected ..

applause and thank you for helping

Comment: @RIDWAN Did you also test the second version, working without using clipboard? With the possibility to have text instead of date (as your code tried to do...)?

Comment: @FanDuru yes, I tested the second version of the code you provided, and it worked as well as I expected without any issues.

thank you your input was very helpful. :)